AttributeError: module 'telethon.tl.functions.messages' has no attribute 'GetAllChatsRequest'
I'm encountering an issue while trying to extract all chat IDs from a group and channel using Telethon. Here's the code snippet I'm using:
@tejas.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, pattern=r'.list'))
async def hello(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    all_chats = tejas(functions.messages.GetAllChatsRequest(except_ids=[]))
    for _, chat in enumerate(all_chats.chats):
        print(chat.title)
        await tejas.send_message(chat, chat.title)


However, when running this code, I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 570, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "c:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Desktop\tes\main.py", line 12, in hello
    all_chats = tejas(functions.messages.GetAllChatsRequest(except_ids=[]))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
AttributeError: module 'telethon.tl.functions.messages' has no attribute 'GetAllChatsRequest'. Did you mean: 'GetAllDraftsRequest'?


I'm unsure why this error is occurring, as I believe I'm following the Telethon documentation correctly. Could someone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

There is no method GetAllChatsRequest listed in the Telethon documentation.
